# Display all images one by one laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On the backend side, my pictures are loaded normally, but I have problems with displaying them on the front

My Model

```
public function getImageUrl(): ?string
{
  return $this->imageUrl('image');
}
```

I am trying to display all the images on the page like this

My page.blade.php

```
<?php
use App\Models\Image;

/**
* @var Image[] $images
*/
?>

<h1>Images</h1>

@foreach($images as $image)
  <img src="{{ $image->getImageUrl() }}">
@endforeach
```

But I am getting an error: Undefined variable: $images

I need to declare this variable with an array of pictures somewhere on the client side or what to do?

My Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $images = 

        return view('page', compact('images'));
    }
```

How can I get all the pictures?

Comment: You obviously did not pass the ```$images``` variable to that page so it is not getting it from anywhere. In your second code snippet, is that a model or a controller?

Comment: So many information is missing. Do you have a controller and a view?

Comment: @Innovin I understand that I need a controller on the client side, and pass this variable there

Comment: But what exactly do I need to do in the controller to get all the images?

Comment: Where do you store the images? Do you have a table for it ?

Comment: @Apollo $form->image('image', __('image'))->move(GeneralSettingFlag::PATH_PREFIX_IMAGE) 
this is how i save the image

Comment: PATH_PREFIX_IMAGE constant in the model,  public function getImageUrl() 
getting a link to an image

Comment: So you save them in a directory. In the controller get all the images from the directory and pass it to the view, after that you can iterate it

Comment: @Apollo 
On the backend side, pictures are loaded and are in the database

Comment: Then call the model and assign it  to the $images variable

Comment: $images = Image::all();

Comment: @Apollo Is it possible to do this without a controller? i.e. directly get all the pictures in the file blade.php

Comment: @baby i hope this code is helpful for you

Comment: @baby You can, but I wouldn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here Image is your model name and you need to select all the images so just write done like this **model name : all**

```
$image = Image::all();
```